# How to avoid disk throttling when importing large tables to Sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 10 or so tables in TSV format ranging from 20-60 GB.  I can import each of them by running:

```
create table mytable(mykey TEXT PRIMARY KEY, valuea INTEGER, valueb REAL);
.separator "\t"
.import data_01.tsv mytable
```

It works testing on one of the TSVs, but it grinds the entire system to a halt because of IO.

How do I avoid this?

Some notes:

- No admin privileges
- Lots of memory (256 GB)

Comment: Split the files into smaller ones?

Comment: @Shawn I dont see how that would help, I'd still have to import everything?

Comment: In smaller chunks spread out over more time, yes.